# Subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I have this Python code.

```
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen("airmon-ng check kill", creationflags = subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)
```

Python 2.7.6 on Linux Mint gives me the following error:

```
    subprocess.Popen("airmon-ng check kill", creationflags = subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE'
```

The same on Windows 8.1 gives me this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Ben\Dropbox\Coding\jam.py", line 10, in <module>
subprocess.Popen("airmon-ng check kill", creationflags = subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)
File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 958, in _execute_child
startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: Did you mean to pass `shell=True`?

Comment: Even when I do, I still get: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
subprocess.Popen("airmon-ng check kill", shell=True)
```

Will do what you want, which I presume is to open a shell and execute `airmon-ng check kill` through Python.
I've looked through the [subprocess docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) and the only thing pointing to `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE` states that `creationflags` is only available in Windows which would explain why it doesn't work in Linux Mint.
[The docs for CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE) also states that

> The new process has a new console, instead of inheriting its parent’s console (the default).
>   This flag is always set when Popen is created with `shell=True`.

So just using `shell=True` is the best way to do what you want.

Comment: is there a way to actually open a new terminal window on Linux and execute those commands with python script? I have a script that prints some output and would like to make it open a new terminal window and print that output there.