# Not able to create a new console with subprocess on a Mac

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, subprocess

I have developed a python script that launches few Node.js applications in different consoles. It works on Windows (python version 3.7.3) but can't make it working on Macs (3.7.4_1).

I keep scrolling the python documentation but don't see anything that would be an issue and couple of posts I find in stack overflow do not solve my issue.

Here is the error:

```
subprocess.Popen(['node', 'index.js'],
creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, shell=False)
```

AttributeError: module 'subprocess' has no attribute 'CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE'

Here is the code:

```
def __runProject(self, project):
    print(f'Starting project \'{project.projectName}\'...')
    subprocess.Popen(['node', 'index.js'], creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, shell=False)
    os.chdir(self.__currentWorkingDirectory)
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you see the documentation that says that variable is only available for windows? https://stackoverflow.com/q/29633719/2308683

Comment: Thanks. I had read but missed this part. Still, given I want to open multiple consoles to start multiple processes at the same time, how would you recommend to do? Thank you

Comment: This should work for macOS:
    
    subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/open', '-n', '-a', 'Terminal', '/usr/local/bin/node', 'index.js'], shell=False)

Answer (score 2):

Indeed the macOS terminal is different when it comes to running a command after opening a new one.
The trick is to use the "open" command.
The parameter should actually be a command file to run.
So for running node with the parameter index.js the following code will create a command file (start_node.command) that launches node with the parameter from a new terminal:

```
with open("start_node.command", "w") as f:
    f.write("#!/bin/sh\nnode index.js\n")
    os.chmod('myfile', stat.S_IRUSR | stat.S_IWUSR | stat.S_IRGRP | stat.S_IWGRP | stat.S_IROTH)
subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/open', '-n', '-a', 'Terminal', 'start_node.command'], shell=False)
```

Comment: The parameters to the Terminal has to be with absolute or relative path. No path search is done for the parameters.

Comment: The provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). This provided answer may be correct, but **it could benefit from an explanation**. Code only answers are not considered "good" answers. From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Next time my posts will be more informative.

Comment: The answer can be [edited](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58110482/edit) to explain what's going on.

Comment: Updated the post again. The parameter to the Terminal should actually be a command file that launches the node with the parameter.